# HPM Error occurred while trying to proxy request in Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

I get this error: `[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/artefact from myapp.herokuapp.com to http://localhost:5000 (ECONNREFUSED)` when I deploy my MERN app.

These are the relevant files in terms of proxying and deploying:

setupProxy.js

```
const proxy = require("http-proxy-middleware");

module.exports = app => {
    app.use(proxy("/api/", { target: "http://localhost:5000" }));
};
```

server.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const logger = require("morgan");
const { mongo_uri } = require("./config/config");
const path = require("path");

let cors = require("cors");

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const app = express();
app.use(cors());

// Set up Routes
const artefactRoutes = require("./routes/api/artefact.js");
const userRoutes = require("./routes/api/users.js");
const authRoutes = require("./routes/api/auth.js");

// Connect to MongoDB Database
const dbRoute = mongo_uri;
mongoose
    .connect(dbRoute, { useNewUrlParser: true })
    .then(() => console.log("Connected to Database"))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

// Body Parser Middleware to parse request body into readable json format
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Used for logging
app.use(logger("dev"));

app.use("/api", artefactRoutes);
app.use("/api/users", userRoutes);
app.use("/api/auth", authRoutes);

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../client/build")));

    app.get("*", (req, res) => {
        // relative path
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../client", "build", "index.html"));
    });
}

app.listen(PORT, () =>
    console.log(`Static server has started. Listening on port ${PORT}`)
);
```

static.json (though I'm not sure really what this does as I just found someone do this on another thread but it didn't change anything for me)

```
{
    "root": "build/",
    "clean_urls": false,
    "routes": {
        "/**": "index.html"
    }
}
```

and my scripts in the parent directory package.json

```
"scripts": {
        "start": "concurrently \"cd backend && node server.js\" \"cd client && npm start\"",
        "format": "prettier",
        "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm run build"
    },
```

and it might help to mention that my folder structure is like:

```
-/project
--/client
--/backend
```

Basically the problem I'm having is that I've deployed my react app to heroku and the frontend loads fine, but none of the axios api calls to my backend are returning anything and just give me a 504 timeout error, and in the heroku logs it just says the proxy error. Any help would be much appreciated!